# How to plot a decision tree from lightgbm model IN R?

Tags: r, lightgbm

How do you plot a lightgbm decision tree? I have searched everywhere but I could not find a solution. Here is an example of the model:

```
data(agaricus.train, package = "lightgbm")
train <- agaricus.train

dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(train$data, label = train$label)

data(agaricus.test, package = "lightgbm")

test <- agaricus.test

dtest <- lgb.Dataset.create.valid(dtrain, test$data, label = test$label)

params <- list(objective = "regression", metric = "l2")

valids <- list(test = dtest)

model <- lgb.train(params,
               dtrain,
               100,
               valids,
               min_data = 1,
               learning_rate = 1,
               early_stopping_rounds = 10)
```